# Installing tomcat6 on centos 64

Tags: tomcat6, centos6.4

I've tried:

```
# yum install tomcat6
```

The result is as below:

```
Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================
Install      44 Package(s)

Total size: 25 M
Installed size: 51 M
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/share/java/xml-commons-jaxp-1.3-apis.jar conflicts between attempted installs of xml-commons-jaxp-1.3-apis-0:1.3.04-5.jpp5.noarch and xml-commons-apis-0:1.3.04-3.6.el6.x86_64
```

And I've no idea about what's going wrong with it.

Comment: Where is the rest of the output?

Comment: I'd say you need to do a "yum update" before anything. It probably tries to install stuff from 6.5 and conflicts with the stuff from 6.4.